# Converting uint16 RGB&NIR geotiff image to a uint8 RGB geotiff?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, rgb

I am trying to convert a uint16 geotiff image with 4 bands (RGB&NIR) with LZW compression to a uint8 geotiff image with 3 bands (RGB) without compression. Here is what I have tried:

```
gdal_translate -ot Byte -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 -r cubic "20170729_182758_0f28_3B_AnalyticMS_SR.tif" "output.tif"
```

When I drag and drop the image in QGIS, I get meaningful colours. When I generate a tif file using the above command, the colours are off (looks washed out). Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: QGIS is using a contrast stretch.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/284351/2856

Comment: Thanks! gdal_translate -ot Byte -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 -scale_1 98 854 -scale_2 196 1028 -scale_3 182 1102 -r cubic "20170729_182758_0f28_3B_AnalyticMS_SR.tif" "output.tif"